# Gatling: loop x times pulling values from a feeder

Tags: gatling

I'd like to achieve something along these lines

- Load scenario with user from a user feeder
- Perform a login for the user
- Perform a limited number (in a loop) of http calls **from another different, random, feeder**

Is what I'm asking achievable? With Feeds?? Here is an outline of what I have but without the bit where in each iteration of the loop I can get data from another feed:

```scala
val userFeeder = csv( "users.csv" )
val randomPagesFeeder = csv( "pages.csv" ).random

object login {
  val dologin = exec(
    http("login page")
      .get("/login")
      .headers(standardHeaders)
    )
    .exec(
      http("post login form")
        .post("/loginaction")
        .headers(standardHeaders)
        .formParam("loginid","${loginid}")
        .formParam("password", "${password}")
    )

  )
)

object randompages {
  val visitrandom = repeat(10){
     // ??? how to pull from feeder in here so that exec( http ) calls
     // have data from randomPagesFeeder, i.e.:
    exec(
      http("randompage")
        .get("${uriFromAFeeder}")
    )
  }
)

def myload() = {
    feed( userFeeder ).exec( login.dologin, randompages.visitrandom )
}
val scn = scenario( "My scenario" ).exec( myload() )

setUp( scn.inject( rampUsers( userCount ).during( userWarmup.toInt seconds ) ) ).protocols( httpProtocol )
```

I suspect that this is a simple problem and the answer is in front of me. I have spent a long time with the docs and other tutorials and am hitting a wall of understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The understanding that I was missing was how feeders work. When you call `feed( feeder )`, you are pulling the next value(s) from the feed into the session to be used in your chain. From [the docs](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/):

> Every time a virtual user reaches this step, it will pop a record out of the Feeder, which will be injected into the user’s Session, resulting in a new Session instance.

**These `feed( feeder )` calls can be chained alongside `exec()`, `pause()`, `each()`, etc. This means you can pull the next value from any feed within a loop, for example.** *This placement of `feed( feeder )` calls is harder to find in the docs and was the source of my misunderstanding.*

The below code illustrates the use of loops combined with feeds (NOT a full or real test scenario, just meant to illustrate how two feeders can be used in combination):

```scala
val usersFeeder = csv( "users.csv" )
val pagesFeeder = csv( "pages.csv" ).random

// ...

feed(userFeeder) // puts the next user from the feed in session
  .exec(
    http("Login page")
      .get("/login")
  )
  .exec(
    http( "Do login" )
      .post( "/loginaction" )
      .formParam("loginid","${loginid}") // loginid from userfeeder
      .formParam("password", "${password}") // password from userfeeder
  )
  .repeat(5) {
    feed(pagesFeeder) // puts the next page from pagesFeeder into session
      .exec(
        http("Visit random page")
          .get("${pageuri}") // pageUrifrom pagesFeeder
      )

  }
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

> LOOP OVER userFeeder

Don't do that, it doesn't make any sense. Have each virtual user simulate a real one and use dedicated credentials instead of recycling them.

> LOOP 10 times getting new entry from resourceFeeder each time

Check [Gatling repeat loop](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#loop-statements). Honestly, those are basic questions, you should have a look at the official [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/) and [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/).

Comment: > Don't do that, it doesn't make any sense.

That is pseudo-code, my use of the feeder is exactly as I have seen in the documentation - I realise my terminology is not quite on point.

I have read the docs on repeat loops and they are only *part* of the question. Within each loop, I'd like to be getting the next item from feed into the session so that I can use it dynamically. Or some other method to pull a random item from a feed.

Basic questions are allowed you know. Folks find the answer to them on SO. And I can't find any examples of what I'm after in the docs or elsewhere.

Comment: Please refrain from calling people trying to help you "grumpy" on Twitter, that's an utter lack of respect. Do your real users on your actual application login, do some stuff, then logout, then login again, etc? They probably don't. If you do that, you'll be reusing resources (connections, caches), resulting in an artificially optimisation.

Comment: I'll figure out an answer myself and post it. Being a noob, the question is most likely badly framed as the terminology of both Scala and the Gatling DSL are not in my bones. BUT, the user scenario and use of user feed is straight out of docs and tutorials I have followed - ramping users that can run a chain. It is part of a wider test and I'd like within a chain for a given user to be able to pull from a random feeder for various calls to avoid hardcoding scenarios and hitting cache optimisations and false scenarios.

Comment: Searching "gatling loop" in google gives you sample code that you can copy and paste. Not showing "research effort" in a question is downvote worthy, as you can see at the tooltip. It was fair to point that out. Own that up and don't act offended.

Comment: I didn't ask how to do a loop. I'll rephrase the question better and provide the answer which will be useful for folks in the future trying to do the same thing (which I'm sure is simple, but just need a nudge in the right direction).

Comment: Hopefully the answer I have given is both correct and helps clarify what the question was (needing to loop and pull from a feed). I think Gatling is great. I find the docs hard to consume - but I also appreciate them and understand how hard it is to do them well. Apologies for being pissy - I would totally accept those comments as comments on the post to help push in the right direction, but they don't work as an answer.

Comment: @dom_watson I have read your questions and answers and comments and still have little idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have literally just finished reframing the question. The understanding I was lacking was how feeds work and putting it together in different ways and how things can be chained. I understand noob questions seem stupid when the workings of things are in your bones. Hopefully my edited question and answer help someone. I don't understand Stephane's assertion about my scenario - I think he was going from my pseudo code that had all the wrong phrasing. My users login once and then do a bunch of stuff and I think I have that correct.

Comment: A more realistic scenario we have where this is used is where we are expecting a large number of logins and then users booking from a pool of events. Rather than have a fixed pattern of events that each user books, we'd like a bit of randomness around the events that each user visits (to avoid unrealistic cache optimisation, etc.). Feeds seemed an elegant solution to this and what I have in my answer works for me and I feel is the right way to use them (or at least not totally wrong).